# will there be any change in time complexity on increasing the number of pegs from 3 to 4,5... in the tower of hanoi problem?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

if there are 4 pegs in the tower of hanoi instead of the traditional tower of hanoi with 3 pegs will there be any change in the time comlexity of the code (cpp), this is a data structure and algorithm question, the only change in the answer will be that in case of 4 pegs the number of moves will decrease right?

i am expecting that there will be no change in time complexities of the code of traditional tower of hanoi and TOH with 4 pegs.

Comment: Why did you tag this as `dsa`?  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i am sorry i will change that

Comment: Typically, time complexity is a function of some input variables (e.g. `n`, but you may see others) that represents a bound on the expected runtime. So if your time complexity is `O(f(pegs) + g(disks))` for arbitrary functions `f` and `g` (note `+` is an assumption!), then increasing the number of `pegs` will only affect `f`. In the typical Hanoi tower game, you only have 3 pegs, and the complexity for solving it is bound only by the number of disks `n` requiring `2^n - 1` moves.

Comment: You reasoning is not rigorous. With antecedent `p` being "*time complexity is O(f(pegs) + g(disks))*" and consequent `q` being "*the complexity for solving it is bound only by the number of disks n requiring 2^n - 1 moves*" what you are saying is: since `p⇒q`, then `q`. As you do not show `p` is true, you can draw no conclusion about `q`.

Comment: BTW, you do not show `p⇒q` is true either... Example: let the complexity be `O(g(fisks) / f(pegs))` (you say yourself `+` is an assumption). What if `f` is the number of attractors of the logistic equation (see https://geoffboeing.com/2015/03/chaos-theory-logistic-map/) (you say yourself `f` is arbitrary so why not this)? It is known to jump from finite to infinite values chaotically. Here, it could mean that there are some numbers of pegs for which the complexity is constant. Not intuitive (and not what the actual complexity is) but mathematically possible with an incomplete reasoning.

Comment: @Atmo sure, I was merely using `f+g` as a demonstrative example, not a rigorously correct form w/ all variables (which I also assumed would be rather ugly typed out). If we went down the rabbit hole, I suppose it'd likely be better to say `O(pegs, disks)` (a function of two inputs), removing this ambiguity. Though that is also not really a commonly-seen form either... Regarding `p` vs. `q` in your comment, note `q` is for the 3-peg solution, and there is no implication that `p->q`, as `p` is an example complexity of the OP's solution.

Answer (score 2):

The [Frame-Stewart algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Frame%E2%80%93Stewart_algorithm), which is presumed to be optimal for any number of pegs () solves the towers of Hanoi in 2<sup>Θ(<sup>1/(−2)</sup>)</sup> moves ( being the number of disks).

- 3 pegs can be solved in 2 - 1 moves (this is a well-documented algorithm).
- As the number of pegs increases, The time complexity decreases:

  - = 4: 2<sup>Θ(<sup>1/2</sup>)</sup>
  - = 5: 2<sup>Θ(<sup>1/3</sup>)</sup>
  - etc

Note that, as pointed by @PaulHankin in comments, the Θ in each line potentially hides a multiplicative constant that is different at each line.
Even with that in mind, as a function of , each new peg makes the towers of Hanoi increasingly "easy" to solve (which makes sense: if a new peg made it harder, we could just ignore it).

Comment: O(2^(Theta(n^1/(r-2))) is a different complexity class than O(2^n) except when r=3.

Comment: Note the "Theta" in the expression O(2^(Theta(n^1/(r-2))) is also misleading -- the bounding constants affect the complexity class, because for example O(2^n), O(2^2n) and O(2^3n) are all different complexity classes.

Comment: @PaulHankin: thanks again for your comment and do let me know if I have made yet another mistake in my answer.